# How to use post-data in android studio for login? (java to php)

Tags: java, php, android-studio, authentication, http-post

For a school project, we're building a website and app. We use a phpmyadmin database for our website and we're trying to create a login for our app (android studio, java) using this database. Therefore, we're trying to use a http post request in android studio to our webserver, so java to php. However, I don't have a lot of experience in coding and can't really find what I'm looking for on the internet.

So, where do I start?

Comment: use retrofit library for api calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **main-class**, first create `apiclient` connection with `interface` then call the interface `login` function by retrofit call:

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

**Main class**:

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface;
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Response> call = apiInterface.login(email,password);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            //do actions here
                            }
                       
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                    
                    }
                });
```

**ApiInterface**  interface:

```
   public interface ApiInterface {
    
            @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login.php")
    Call<Response> login(@Field("email") String email,
                          @Field("password") String password);
    }
```

**ApiClient** for connection:

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String base_URL = "https://etx.com/android/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){

        if(retrofit==null){

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                            .setLenient()
                            .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Note**: If you still don't understand you can comment and ask me.

Comment: We copied this code into our MainActivity file in Android studio, but the notification "cannot resolve ...." pops up for getApiClient, email, password, enqeue, response and 't'. We were able to resolve the others, but we don't understand what's wrong with these. On top of that, what is the 't' in "throwable t" meant for? Last but not least, do we need anything special to receive our data etc. or is that just a simple php script? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you add ApiClient  class too?

Comment: throwable t meant for the error if api call failed it will show you the error why api call is failed.

Comment: yeah for api you just use simple php and return data in json code like this : json_encode("true");

Comment: We tried again and now there are no reported bugs. Therefore, we tried to start the app with just this code, but the app terminates itself instantly, and we don't understand why? Where could this typically go wrong? Plus, how does this work with a button etc.? We're very unexperienced.. so our php script is also a challenge..

Comment: ask a new question for this add retrofit as reference. However on button onclick you can   call.enqueue the call to send the data by onclick of button.

Comment: Accept this answer and for more details check this out: https://abhiandroid.com/programming/retrofit

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a new question for that

Comment: I managed to get this to fully work, so thanks again! We also managed to check our login data with our database and are now trying to return a true/false with json_encode("true"), like you suggested @ahmad bajwa. However, we don't get this to work. we put ```echo json_encode("true")``` in our php file and tried some different ways of receiving this based off codes we found on the internet. But I think we're making some stupid mistakes. Could you perhaps send me into the right direction or something? Thanks! You'd make my day!

Comment: I'm glad to know that. What do you mean about the direction?

Comment: Well, it seems like we don't receive any data in our android file. So in php I put: ```if(//code which checks valid user login) { echo json_encode("true") }``` In android studio I put: ```String jsonString = "{true}"; JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString); String check = obj.getJSONObject("true").toString(); if (check == "{true}") {//start new activity``` I think I'm doing a few things horribly wrong, but I don't know how to do it correctly and can't  really find any information/tutorials regarding this problem. I was wondering if you knew something that could help me out?

Comment: Hope this help you https://medium.com/@jacinth9/android-retrofit-2-0-tutorial-89de3c714c63

Comment: Got it working. Thanks a lot!!